# Overriding equals method in DTO's

Tags: java

Is it necessary to override equals and hashcode methods in DTO's? Because DTO's are just use for transfer data. Is there any best practice or something regarding this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) offers one piece of advice:

> Objects placed in a List , Set, or Map (as either a key or value) should have an appropriate definition of equals.

Surely DTOs are used for more than just transfer, we do keep them, sort them, cache them ...

In practice do folks provide equals and hash? No not always. Should we? I think so.

Comment: "This is particularly true for "data-centric" classes which map to database records" are DTOs mapped to database records? i would think that would be your entities/POJOs, whereas DTOs are simply for data transfer and shouldn't contain any logic whatsoever.

Comment: There is logic and logic ... If you're going to keep the DTOs in collections then hash and equals are likely to be needed. That doesn't imply adding serious business logic.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not you need to provide `equals` and `hashcode` implementations for your DTO classes depends on how you use them.

If you use them with one or more Collections, you should provide the implementation for the appropriate method. Almost all Collections call `equals` on the objects they store. Hash table based Collections like `HashSet` and `HashMap` call `hashcode`, whereas sorted Collections like `TreeSet` and `TreeMap` call `compareTo` method in addition to `equals`.

Comment: It's worth adding that if you provide `equals` and `hashCode` it is always both of them, or none of them, so you wouldn't break the contract.

docs - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Answer (score 2):

If it becomes too trivial I can recommend using the lombok annotations
http://projectlombok.org/features/